# MySQL looking up more rows than needed (indexing issue)

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization, primary-key, innodb

In our MySQL 5.5 database, we have following InnoDB table with 30M+ rows:

```
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
| participant_id | question_id | given_answer_id | status |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
|       500      |      12     |        25       |    0   |
+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------+
```

The combination participant_id + question_id + given_answer_id is unique.

At the moment we have **following keys**:

PRIMARY KEY (in this order)

- participant_id
- question_id
- given_answer_id

INDEX KEY

- question_id

For this table, we have **two kinds of select queries** in our application:

```
[...] WHERE participant_id = x AND question_id = y AND given_answer_id = z;
```

and

```
[...] WHERE question_id = x;
```

Normally, every participant_id has between 0 and <100 rows with different question_ids. The other way around, every question_id can have unlimited (usually not more than 100 000) rows with different participant_ids. The first query is executed way more often than the second one.

When we execute following query, it shows us that **32096 rows** where looked up:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM example WHERE question_id = 500;

+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key         | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
| 1  | SIMPLE      | example   | ref  | question_id   | question_id | 8       | const | 32096 |       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+-------------+---------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Whereas, when we execute the same query **without EXPLAIN** only **18732 rows are returned**.

What indexes do we need on this table in order to prevent this overhead but still performing for both kinds of queries?

---

Here's is the code to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
    `participant_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `question_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `given_answer_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `status` TINYINT(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    PRIMARY KEY (`participant_id`, `question_id`, `given_answer_id`),
    INDEX `question_id` (`question_id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Better try moving this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The 32096 is just an estimate. If you have an index on question_id and your condition uses "=", you aren't going to do much better unless you go "index only": i.e. create the second index as (question_id, participant_id, given_answer_id, status). That way, the DBMS just has to read the index, and never goes to the base table. However, with 30 million rows, you might not want a large index.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted this question to dba.stackexchange.com, as recommended, and received a comprehensive answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49275/mysql-looking-up-more-rows-than-needed-indexing-issue